# Postgis-get linesubstring from linestring which take parameter as point and startpoint

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a **linestring** which is crossing a given point, so my requirement is to get the **linesubstring** from that **point** to starting point of that **linestring**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ST_Line_Locate_Point`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Locate_Point.html) to identify where in your line is your intersection point, followed by [`ST_Line_Substring`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Line_Substring.html) to get the actual line, from 0 to the position found in the previous step.

The code should be similar to

```
SELECT ST_LINE_SUBSTRING(MyLine, 0, ST_LINE_LOCATE(myLine, myPoint))
```